# how to find data that (userId = a && friendId = b) AND (userId = b && friendId = a) in typeorm?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

how to find data that (userId = a && friendId = b) AND (userId = b && friendId = a) in typeorm ?

[image]

Comment: what is your issue exactly ? can you share what you have tried alredy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `;` in both of your where conditions to `AND`, e.g.:

```
.where("friendMessage.userId = :userId AND friendMessage.userId = :friendId", { userId: item.userId, friendId: item.friendId })
```

---

But I'm not sure that it would be correct, because of `userId` and `friendId` from `item` could be different, but for some reason you want to check that both are suitable for `friendMessage.userId`.
I guess `OR` operator should be used instead of `AND`